# Code complete styling for overridden and implemented methods in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, overriding, code-completion

Does anyone know how to change the autocomplete PHP styling for Overridden/Implemented Methods in Netbeans 6.9.1

I would like to drop the opening curly bracket to the next line. eg

```
public function overriddenMethod()
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating methods using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> Netbeans respects the language specific formating you set in:

```
Tools -> Options -> Formatting Tab
```

Change the `Language`dropdown `php` and after that the `Category` dropdown to `braces`.

Now you can set `new line` for `Method deceleration` and it will create the methods like you want it to.

For me having "method" at "same line" produced this output:

```
public function __get($name) {

}
```

and after changing it do: "next line" it generated:

```
public function __get($name)
{

}
```

---

As an added bonus (just in case you didn't know about that:

Using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> format all existing code according to those rules.

Comment: It might be different in Netbeans 6.9.1, but I found it here: 
Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting-> Language : PHP -> Category : Braces